# Repeated Number count result in Ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i was trying to get counted result in Ascending order

The following is my code

```
  var NewArray = [1,4,5,2,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,4,2,1,7];
  var SortNewArray = NewArray.sort();
  var SortNewArrayLength = SortNewArray.length;
  var prev = SortNewArray[0];
  var count = 1;
   for(var i =0; i<SortNewArrayLength; i++)
   {
     if(SortNewArray[i] == prev)
     {
         count++;
     }
    else
     {
         console.log(SortNewArray[i] + "  comes  " + count + "  times ");
         prev = SortNewArray[i];
         count = 1;
     }
  }
```

this is output i am getting

[image]

whatever i marked in red color. i want those count in ascending order

Please anyone can help me out?

Comment: is this by any means related to `java` or `c`?

Comment: C does not stand for C drive. ;)

Comment: collect the frequencies and resort the list with it.

Comment: this will help, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63947/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-string-returning-list-of-unique-words-sorted-by-fr

Comment: So, to be clear, do you want the output to be sorted by number of occurrences of each number (count), instead of by the original number?

Comment: i want output by number of occurrences of each number(count).

Answer (score 1):

```
var NewArray = [1,4,5,2,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,4,2,1,7];
var counts = {};

// first collect the count of each number
NewArray.forEach( function(n){
   if( counts[n] ){
        counts[n] += 1;   
   }
   else {
        counts[n] = 1;     
   }
});
// now counts = { 1:3, 2:3, 3:1, 4:4, 5:2, 6:1, 7:1 }

// get the keys (unique numbers from NewArray) and sort them by their values (count)
var keys = Object.keys( counts ).sort( function(a, b){
  return counts[a] > counts[b];  
})

// print key:value pairs sorted by value
keys.forEach( function( n ){
  console.log("%s comes %d times", n, counts[n] );  
})

/*
3 comes 1 times
6 comes 1 times
7 comes 1 times
5 comes 2 times
1 comes 3 times
2 comes 3 times
4 comes 4 times
*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s384qq66/

Comment: Thanks its working properly what I am expecting. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `var count = 1;` to `var count = 0;` and change

```
console.log(SortNewArray[i] + "  comes  " + count + "  times ");
```

to

```
console.log(SortNewArray[i-1] + "  comes  " + count + "  times ");
```